# Do IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0 have a web server plugin like in version 8.5?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, ibm-was

Do IBM WebSphere Application Server  7.0 have a web server plugin like in version 8.5? or in WAS7 we need IIS as a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what Gas has pointed out, if you intend to use a web server in front of your WebSphere Application Server (WAS) deployment, installing the WAS HTTP Plugin on the web server is a requirement.

All versions of WAS have this requirement and offer a plugin for the following web servers:

- IBM HTTP Server (IHS)
- Apache HTTP Server
- Domino Web server
- Internet Information Services (IIS)
- Sun Java Web server

The plugin itself is available on the "Supplements" image for which ever WAS bundle you're licensed for. The following document provides the appropriate WAS v7 part numbers for each OS:

[Download WebSphere Application Server Version 7.0 for Windows operating systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012956)

The "Supplements" image is Download 3 in the list, and is a two part download.

Also, here is the Plugin install parent doc from the WAS v7 Knowledge Center:

[Installing Web server plug-ins](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tins_webplugins.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every WAS version has Plugin for most major web servers (IHS, Apache, IIS). You need to download separate package, known as Supplements. There you will find WebSphere Plugins.